# Fast and lightweight photo viewer

Tags: windows, gratis, image-viewer

Since the Microsoft Windows 10 Photo App [has issues displaying images](https://superuser.com/questions/1572639/photo-app-does-not-display-photos) and that re-occurs every 2 to 3 days, I'm looking for an alternative.

The software must

- display images
- move forward and backward in a directory of files with a left/right button
- be able to delete files
- be gratis
- be able to rotate files in 90° steps
- be able to zoom and pan images
- support PNG, JPG, BMP, TIF (and hopefully some more)
- have a short startup time ²)
- not have too many other features

I have tried

- [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.de/), but it has too many features. It also "displays" WAV files, which is disturbing.

²) Must be less than a second, possibly much shorter. IrfanView is very good in ths aspect. I can hardly measure it, but I guess it's ~ 100ms. You can assume SSD, 8 GB of RAM and an i7-class processor.

Comment: If you have a modern wide-gamut monitor you will also want it to support ICM color profiles, and make sure to install the monitor profile. Otherwise you’ll be unhappy with the color rendering (over saturation).  The default Windows 10 Photo Viewer is inexplicably still not color-managed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the **Pictureflect Photo Viewer** (https://pictureflect.com/). The Software can be downloaded in the Microsoft Store.

It has a free version and it meets all the given requirements. Moreover it has a modern, Windows 10 styled look. I did not try it but this App should work well with touchscreen devices

Answer (score 2):

You can also re-enable Windows Photo Viewer, which is still installed in Windows 10 and seems to have almost all your requirements.

You need to manipulate Windows Registry using following:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open]
"MuiVerb"="@photoviewer.dll,-3043"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\DropTarget]
"Clsid"="{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\DropTarget]
"Clsid"="{60fd46de-f830-4894-a628-6fa81bc0190d}"
```

There are various articles that provide a step by step guide on how to do it:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14312-restore-windows-photo-viewer-windows-10-a.html

or

https://www.howtogeek.com/225844/how-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10/

or

[https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-windows-photo-viewer-back-in-windows-10/#:~:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20open%20the,it%20can%20open%20by%20default](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-windows-photo-viewer-back-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20open%20the,it%20can%20open%20by%20default).

Comment: Greetings, it would be good if you copied the important information and credited the respective links, in case the link gets broken/removed. As it stands, the answer is a link-only answer and susceptible to be flagged and (possibly) deleted.